# npm install react-native-ibm-mobilefirst --save gives me error

Tags: windows, react-native, npm, ibm-mobilefirst

> react-native-ibm-mobilefirst@8.0.2018072413 postinstall D:\Call4Code\MyTestApp
>   \node_modules\react-native-ibm-mobilefirst
>   chmod +x scripts/postinstall.sh && ./scripts/postinstall.sh

'chmod' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react-native@3.2.1 requires a peer of eslint@^3.17.0 || ^
4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fse
vents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@
1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}
)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-native-ibm-mobilefirst@8.0.2018072413 postinstall: `chmod +x scri
pts/postinstall.sh && ./scripts/postinstall.sh`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-native-ibm-mobilefirst@8.0.2018072413 postinstall s
cript.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\shalvi_kubal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-08-16T10
_34_10_364Z-debug.log

Comment: currently ibm-react-native-mobilefirst package support is not available for windows

Comment: you can join the mobileFirst slack community 

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2017/05/26/come-chat-with-us/

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is a workaround that I used to install the react-native-ibm-mobilefirst plugin. You can create your react native project from macOS and then install the react-native-ibm-mobilefirst plugin from there, and then copy that project folder from macOS to windows. Then run 'npm install' inside the project folder and it will work fine.